# Is it possible (or suggested) to run Solr/Jetty with Varnish?

Tags: varnish, solr

If yes, I would choose Turpentine as the extension for Varnish.

Are there specific port settings to avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

It is **possible**, though the two technologies have very little to do with each other.

Solr is a search indexing engine for on-site search of your product content. Solr support is included in Magento Enterprise Edition. Magento Enterprise also has the ability to run other parts of the store from Solr, such as layered navigation and category listing pages.

The Turpentine extension from Nexcess treats certain block types **as if they were dynamic content**, and Turpentine **replaces** these blocks with either an [ESI (edge-side include)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes) or an AJAX call to populate these blocks.

Other pieces of functionality that are enabled in EE's Solr integration include search suggestion and spelling correction - neither of these two blocks are accounted-for in the Nexcess module.

It seems as if Turpentine can be easily configured to hole-punch these blocks by name; and in worst-case scenario it seems you can wrap them in an ESI yourself. It's up to you to provide AJAX functionality for these blocks, though that should be relatively simple to you if you're at the level of integrating this kind of functionality into your site.